# Help with limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x*(3^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)}$

Tags: limits

So I cannot solve this limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1{x(3^{1/x}-1)}$$ I've tried Wolfram alpha but it just gives me the result without the process

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: you can see it as $\frac{1/x}{3^{1/x}-1}$, so that you can use de l'hopital

Comment: You can simplify to $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac x{3^x-1}=(\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{3^x-1}x)^{-1}$ and apply the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Let `u = 1/x`, then as `x` goes to infinity, `u` goes to 0. Thus,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x(3^\frac{1}{x} - 1)} = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{u}{3^u - 1}$

Now we can use L'Hôpital's rule, as the numerator and denominator both go to 0. Thus we get

$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{u}{3^u - 1} = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}u}{\frac{d}{dx}(3^u - 1)} = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{ln(3) * 3^u}$

Applying the limit, we get the following:

$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{ln(3) * 3^u} = \frac{1}{ln(3)*3^0} = \frac{1}{ln(3)}$

Thus the solution to the problem is

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x(3^\frac{1}{x} - 1)} = \frac{1}{ln(3)}$

This hopefully helps

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ so $x\rightarrow \infty, t\rightarrow 0$, then you have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1/x}{3^{1/x}-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t}{3^t-1}=L.$ Considering $L\neq 0$, we have that $1/L=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{3^t-1}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(3^t\right)|_{t=0}=\ln(3).$ So $L=\frac{1}{\ln(3)}$ and we are done.